# How to query nearby sites by geography?

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry, gis, geo

I use SQL Server 2014 as my database, it has 1 million rows of data in one table, how to query nearby sites by geography column?

Does SQL Server have any such functions?

We should consider about performance.

Example:

```
select top 10 
from table1 
where nearby(latlng) < 10(miles)
```

Comment: If you want to compute distances using latitude and longitude, you will need the Haversine formula.

Comment: Can you better describe what geographical information you currently store in your database? Depending on what is available to you it may radically change your approach.

Comment: I store in two format, one is float type latitude and longitude,
the other is geography format in SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a geography column, called Location for example, to the TABLE1.  Make sure you create a spatial index for that column to improve performance of spatial queries.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY TABLE1.Location.STDistance(latlng) DESC
```